# Failing to prettify URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm in the process of trying to prettify my URLs

From: http://localhost/blog.php?id=1

To: http://localhost/blog/1

I've added the below to my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ blog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

From my understanding that should now redirect when I call my "to" url in PHP **header("location: /blog/".id);** it takes me to the relevant page, and my **$_GET['id']** should have a value. It's coming up empty

I've been messing around with a few different regular expressions, but I don't think that's the issue.

In the apache config I changed "AllowOverride" to 'All'

To check to see if the .htaccess was even being used I put in some invalid regex, and got an error in apache_error.log

I've been on a ton of different pages asking the same thing, and watched plenty of YouTube vids, but I can't see what I'm missing

Comment: Could you please do confirm if you are hitting link http://localhost/blog.php?id=1 in browser? And you want to change it to link http://localhost/blog/1 link in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 "blog.php?id=1" works successfully. And yes, I'd like to change it to "blog/1"

Answer (score 3):

Have your htaccess Rules file in following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
##Rules for external redirect to blog/1 here.
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Rules for internal rewrite to blog.php file here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

##Rules for internal rewrite to index.php file here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: That's now worked in the sense that it converts my URL to what I was asking, but no page actually loads. Getting "Not Found" on all URLs

Comment: @Oyyou, ok could you please do let me know what sample url you are hitting? Also are urls starting with `blog` going to served by blog.php right? Please confirm me on these, cheers.

Comment: @Oyyou, Also please make sure your htaccess file is present besides blogs.php file in your apache server.

Comment: My .htaccess file is in the base directory along with the index.php, and blog.php. Now when I type "../blog?id=1" it takes me to "..blog/1". Which is what I asked for. But now none of the pages are being found. When I remove "-MultiViews" everything is found, and my URL is changed, but the $_GET["id"] doesn't have a value

Comment: @Oyyou, ok sure, I have changed riles now, could you please do check them once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Now the URLs are changing, but it's only showing the index.php content

Comment: @Oyyou, Please place `-MultiViews` in rules once Also make sure all rules shown in my post are kept as it is, let me know.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. -MultiViews is only in there once?

Comment: @Oyyou, yes please keep `-Multiviews` there as its shown in my rules, since you mentioned you removed it from rules, so I requested to keep it in my rules, kindly do test it once and let me know, cheers.

Comment: Apologies - I've been using your full version and no luck. My URLs are changing, but the page is staying the same (index.php

Comment: @Oyyou, could you please do let me know what is sample URL you are hitting?

Comment: If I clicked on my "dashboard" link, the URL changes to "localhost/dashboard", but the page and content doesn't change from my "index.php". The same applies to all URLs I try and go to

Comment: @Oyyou, so when you hitting http://localhost/blog.php?id=1 does it redirect to http://localhost/blog/1 URL? Please confirm once.

Comment: It no longer redirects

Comment: @Oyyou, these rules are working fine for me. Could you please do let me know if you have other rules also apart from these ones?

Comment: @Oyyou, along with my above question to you, please try my edited Rules once, there was a typo, I fixed it now, let me know.

Comment: Same issue. URL change but page stays as index.php

Comment: @Oyyou, these rules are working fine for me. Could you please do let me know if you have other rules also apart from these ones?

Answer (score 0):

try this .
1.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule blog/id/(.*)/ blog.php?id=$1
RewriteRule blog/id/(.*) blog.php?id=$1
```

example url :-      http://localhost/blog/id/1/

Directory Type URL

Comment: No luck I'm afraid!